# Pivot or unpivot a table

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table in SQL that I need to pivot or unpivot (not sure which).  The table consists of days (as represented by workdays##1, workdays##2, workdays##3,etc.) The values under these days are a business day value for the month.  Other columns in this table are Company, Year, Monthnum which should remain as columns.  So it looks something like this:
[SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTC4s.jpg)

```
Company   Year    Monthnum   workday##1  workday##2  workday##3   workday##4
  US      2016        8            1          2           3            4
```

I need the workday##'s (renamed as day of month and substringed to just the number portion) to pivot to rows and the values under them to be put in one column with the header businessday.  [Future](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmMEa.png)

```
Company   Year    Monthnum       Dayofmonth      Businessday
    US    2016        8        1 (workday##1)         1
    US    2016        8        2 (workday##2)         2
    US    2016        8        3 (workday##3)         3
    US    2016        8        4 (workday##4)         4
```

This table represents the year and month and the number of business days per month.  From this I will be doing some month to date calculations against sales goals on a daily basis.

Comment: You are looking for unpivot, but the answer totally depends on which database you are using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.).  That being said, which database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Typically, a good question will have all necessary information inside as text, not as external images.  Please edit your question and provide a minimal sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have added samples in the text.